# How to set a pointers memory address?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to Write process memory to change values in a game. I think I found the pointer that points to the "health" value. I believe that `0x17F10D12520` is the pointer to the memory address but when I try to

```
    DWORD *point;
    point = 0x17F10D12520;
```

It throws

```
a value of type long long" cannot be assigned to an entity of type
"DWORD *"
```

It also throws

```
 Error  C2440   '=': cannot convert from '__int64' to 'DWORD64 *'
```

Comment: do you mean you are calling WriteProcessMemory?

Comment: Looks like you forgot something. My guess would be to cast it. Perhaps something like `tocstring`? Also, using direct memory addresses is bad.

Comment: So, first off, are you compiling 64 bit code? Because if not, a pointer is highly unlikely to be able to hold a >32 bit address. `point = static_cast<DWORD*>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(0x17F10D12520));` (multi-step may not be needed) should silence the compiler, though of course, if that address doesn't actually point to valid memory it will break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to cast it to pointer.

```
point = (DWORD *) 0x17F10D12520;
```

Comment: This answer seems unsure. Do you mean to say "cast it to a pointer because..." or are you genuinely unsure of whether this even works?

Comment: @Tas my guess is he isn't 100% sure of OP's problem because OP has no [MCVE] (but close).

Comment: @Tas this is the way to assign an address to pointer manually, so it can solve the compile error OP got. Whether it works depends on if the address is valid.